# Strange results SVAR impulse response functions in r

Tags: r, statistics, economics

I am trying to compute the impulse response functions of a Structural VAR system composed of 5 quarterly time series variables:

```
Uncertainty = 0.01516483 0.01576851 0.01514961 0.01505102 0.01512489 0.01507230 0.01527489 0.01542124 0.01542613 0.01588306 0.01535583 0.01521866 0.01532704 0.01561553 0.01533545 0.01546499 0.01541305 0.01521282 0.01519695 0.01518378 0.01549650 0.01567024 0.01525345 0.01524214 0.01528679 0.01551463 0.01523704 0.01593742 0.01612399 0.01616118 0.01560939 0.01596426 0.01619084 0.01638339 0.01629785 0.01648435 0.01814780 0.01744788 0.01975361 0.01567541 0.01547753 0.01641009 0.01568128 0.01552354

Bank Rates = 4.750000 4.750000 4.583333 4.500000 4.500000 4.500000 4.666667 4.916667 5.250000 5.416667 5.750000 5.666667 5.333333 5.000000 5.000000 3.166667 1.000000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000

Net Trade = -2232 -2355 -2480 -2423 -2411 -2361 -2739 -2655 -3026 -2974 -3227 -2487 -3333 -2631 -2291 -1850 -2042 -2122 -2078 -2246 -2468 -2196 -2481 -2606 -2276 -1876 -1897 -1881 -1855 -2126 -2149 -3058 -2169 -2338 -2353 -2807 -2805 -2912 -3104 -2799 -3444 -3654 -4052 -3769

Employment = 73.3 72.9 73.1 73.1 72.9 72.7 73.5 74.2 74.5 74.9 74.2 74.3 74.3 73.9 73.3 73.1 72.0 71.8 71.5 69.9 70.1 70.7 71.2 71.0 71.6 71.1 70.9 71.1 71.3 70.5 70.8 71.6 72.2 72.7 72.5 73.2 73.5 73.9 74.2 74.4 74.1 74.1 74.6

GDP =  81.7  83.3  83.3  84.4 84.4  84.7  85.6  86.2 86.4  87.1  88.0  89.7 89.2  91.7  93.3  94.2 93.2  93.4  94.5  94.3 95.0  96.0  96.1  96.5 98.3  99.2  99.5  99.6 99.8  99.9 100.3 100.0 101.8 101.7 102.8 102.8 103.2 103.4 103.5 103.8 103.1 103.2 103.9 104.0
```

Which according to the Augmented Dickey Fuller test are all stationary. Moreover, while checking for cointegration between pairs of time series none is found (Engle-Granger test).

After grouping all the variables:

```
Sample = cbind(Uncertainty Bank Rates, Net Trade, Employment, GDP )
```

I attempt to study the optimal number of lags to use for the var:

```
VARselect(Sample, lag.max = 20, type="const")
```

which tells me 6.... Here is the first problem: unrealistic number of lags for quarterly data.... Moreover, when applying the test to each individual series most of them showed 2 as the optimal number of lags. With this in mind, I try to calculate the SVAR using the cholesky decomposition of the error variance-covariance matrix and picture the impulse response functions:

```
var <- VAR(Sample, p=2, type = "both")
var

amat <- diag(5)
diag(amat) <- NA
svar.a <- SVAR(var, estmethod = "direct", Amat = amat)
plot(irf(svar.a, impulse = "Topic.15", 
         response = c("BankRates", "NetTrade", "Employ.per", "GDP"), 
         n.ahead = 20, ortho = TRUE, 
         cumulative = FALSE, 
         boot = TRUE, ci = 0.95, 
         runs = 100))
```

For which I get:

[image: Impulse response functions using 2 lags]

Comment: I just want to note, that your series do not look stationary (GDP mostly never is). How did you check it? I.e., by ``library(urca); summary(ur.df(GDP, type = 'drift', selectlags = 'AIC'))`` the resulting t-statistics are way lower than all of the critical values, which implies non-stationarity.

Comment: @AndresAzqueta Help use out a bit, what exactly is the problem?  That being said, there is a lot going on here the may be a problem.  First, the y axis scale is not inline with the scale of all your variables.  The IRF appear squished for this reason.  Bank rates are on the order of 1e0 and your scale is on the order of 1e7.

Comment: @AndresAzqueta another problem is that the cholesky decomposition imposes a casual relationship between variables.  It is essential that you justify this causal relationship.  I'm no macro economics, but low GDP in a quarter may affect unemploy and the vice versa is also plausible.  If a simultaneous relationship of this nature exist, you can utilize the cholesky decomposition.

Comment: @AndresAzqueta what is your sample size. If the time series variables you supply represents the entire sample, when you simply don't have enough data.  A VAR with 6 lags and 5 variables will estimate 35 parameter estimates.  Your above sample has 30-40 Obs, so you essentially have no degrees of freedom.

Comment: @AndresAzqueta last one I promise.  I am, like Nutle, suspicious of your unit root test.  Again I'm not a macro economist, however, if you google "is GDP (or Unemployment) trend stationary" the literature suggests that it is, however, with a very important caveat.  There are regime shifts (i.e. structural breaks).  Previous analysis which did not account for such structural breaks falsely discovered unit roots.  What does this mean for you.  First, your unit root test should probably find a unit root.  A simple test which accounts for structural breaks is Zivot-Andrews (`urca::ur.za`).

Comment: (cont ....) Second, you will need to incorporate identified structural breaks in your VAR analysis.  If you don't you will get wrong and potentially weird results.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer guys, I double checked and indeed the series are not stationary. I guess I have to take first differences then. @Jacob, totally right about the Cholesky decomposition, it imposes restriction in the shocks, being the top variable the one that affects the rest. I am following this order from a paper that has conducted similar results. Also, very interesting idea to check for regime shifts, lets see if it still holds after taking first differences of the variables. I will update the question, cheers!